# ggplot add cutoff abline to a stacked barplot where condition: threshold reached

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to draw a vertical line separating the competitors taking the largest share from the rest, say 70% of the market.
Here is example data.

```
# Example data

data<- tibble::tribble(
  ~CUSTOMER, ~COMPETITOR, ~VALUE,
      "AAA",    "XXX",  123400,
      "AAA",    "YYY",   10000,
      "AAA",    "ZZZ",   80000,
      "AAA",    "YYY",   60000,
      "BBB",    "XXX",  110000,
      "BBB",    "YYY",   20000,
      "BBB",    "ZZZ",   10000,
      "BBB",    "YYY",   80000,
      "CCC",    "YYY",   30000,
      "CCC",    "ZZZ",   12000,
      "DDD",    "YYY",    7000,
      "CCC",    "VVV",   10000)
```

Here is my aggregation for the plot:

```
library (tidyverse) 
   df_COMP<- data %>%                          # totals and pareto for COMPETITOR
      group_by(COMPETITOR) %>%      
      summarise(COMP_VALUE=sum(VALUE)) %>%                                 
      arrange(desc(COMP_VALUE)) %>% 
      mutate(COMP_PARETO=cumsum(COMP_VALUE)/total_VALUE) %>%  
      ungroup()
```

I plot a stacked barplot ordered descending.

```
df_COMP %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_reorder(COMPETITOR, -COMP_VALUE), 
                               y = COMP_VALUE)) + 
  geom_col(alpha=0.4, aes(fill=COMPETITOR), col = "darkgray", show.legend = F)+
  ggtitle(" ")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 11)+ col_competitors  +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=10),
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank())+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(n){unit_mln(n)}, 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~. / sum(df_COMP$COMP_VALUE), labels = scales::percent))+
  scale_x_discrete()+
  geom_text(aes(label = unit_mln(COMP_VALUE)), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

How to add to this stacked barplot, a hline separating the competitors at the threshold, say 70% based on COMP_PARETO column which contains cumulative % of sales. It would be easy if x axis were numeric but they are categorical.

Comment: @JackekKotowski, something wrong with your code. Can't reproduce it. Getting the error, `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :  Evaluation error: object 'total_VALUE' not found.` Looks like the variable, `total_VALUE` is undefined in the given code.

Comment: @JacekKotowski, Also, `col_competitors` and `unit_mln()`; the former is something you're trying to add to the plot, and the latter is some function - from a package or self-defined?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `geom_hline` and for some reason it didn't work? Because it shouldn't make a difference whether x is discrete.

Comment: @camille I have no idea how to add hline when x axis is categorical, not numerical.

Comment: Try doing the same as if x were numeric. It should work the same way, and there's no harm in trying

Comment: Thanks @camille I will experiment with it.